# SQLite: replace result values using bijective table

Tags: sqlite, join, mapping, resultset, self-join

In SQLite, I have the following query

```
SELECT x.nameIndex, y.nameIndex
FROM relation x, relation y
WHERE x.label=y.label AND x.feature=1 AND y.feature=0;
```

which returns all pairs of `x.nameIndex,y.nameIndex` with the same label where `x` has feature `1` and `y` has feature `0`.

Now I have another table `index2name` where I store the name for each index, where I could do like:

```
SELECT name FROM index2name WHERE nameIndex=...;
```

How can I change the top query such that it looks up the name for the respective indeces and returns pairs of names instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) which returns the name instead of the indexes and the group for each row in `relation` (by a join to `index2name`) and do a self join on that:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT i.name, r.label, r.feature 
  FROM relation r INNER JOIN index2name i
  ON i.nameIndex = r.nameIndex
)
SELECT c1.name, c2.name 
FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte c2
ON c2.label = c1.label
WHERE c1.feature=1 AND c2.feature=0;
```

Or without the `CTE`:

```
SELECT i1.name, i2.name 
FROM relation r1 INNER JOIN relation r2
ON r2.label = r1.label
INNER JOIN index2name i1 ON i1.nameIndex = r1.nameIndex 
INNER JOIN index2name i2 ON i2.nameIndex = r2.nameIndex 
WHERE r1.feature=1 AND r2.feature=0;
```

Comment: Oh I guess I should not have called it `.group` in the example ;)

Comment: `group` is a reserved word. You can use it enclosed inside backticks or square brackets.

Comment: I realized that the additional query term that I had skipped before now makes it harder than expected for me to understand how to include it in your `INNER JOIN` examples. Could you adapt your answer to my edits? Sorry...

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you see a performance (complexity) difference between the two alternatives suggested by you?

Comment: If your SQLite version supports CTEs then use the 1st query. It is better in terms of readability, maintainability and I believe efficiency since it is easier for any optimizer to design a proper execution plan. In most cases I think it will perform better.